# Site on portrait mode displays a title too big

Tags: html, css

I was making the main of the site today and I added two `<div>`s. I made it perfectly so on every monitor it will display the same. However, when I tried opening it on my phone on portrait mode, the title is bigger than the free space for the `<div>` and the two `<div>`s are going one under one.

It’s OK for me because there are phones with a much smaller screen than mine. But the `<div>` size is staying the same; it’s not going up to 100% to fit all the screen if it’s one under one. It’s staying the same 70% and 30% and it’s awful. Here are some images of that:

[image]

And this is the code:

```css
#glavno {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.reklami {
  display: inline-table;
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.novo {
  display: inline-table;
  top: 0;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}
.naslovnovosti {
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: #41c2ac;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}
.naslovreklami {
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: #41c2ac;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="glavno">
  <div class="novo">
    <div class="naslovnovosti">
      Новости
    </div>
    novost1
    <hr>novost2
    <hr>novost3
    <hr>novost4
    <hr>novost1 novost2 novost3 novost4

  </div>
  <div class="reklami">
    <div class="naslovreklami">
      Реклами
    </div>
    deneska se sluci cudo vo valandovo
    <hr>novost2
    <hr>novost3
    <hr>novost4
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `@media` rule in your CSS, instructing the browser to substitute 100% (instead of 70% and 30%) as soon as the window width is less than X, where X is what you think to be the good choice for this to happen.

It'd look like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .reklami {width: 100%;}
    .novo {width: 100%;}
}
```